# what tense to use when summarizing an episode of a TV show

Tags: tense, past-perfect, present-tense

I don't know whether to use present tense or past tense to make a summary of a TV show episode. MasterChef is an example

Comment: It's a stylistic choice, but [Vulture TV Recap](https://www.vulture.com/tv-recaps/) is a typical site giving episode reviews. As you'll see, they use Present tense. And so would I - it gives a more "immediate" feel, so it's more attention-grabbing.

Comment: so if I want to write my feelings about some events in one episode when I use the present tense, I also use the present tense to express my feelings, right?. For example, I am surprised at the decision of the judges in that episode of the TV show

Comment: Yes - it's quite natural to say *I **am** surprised at the decision of the judges...* even though the "surprise" probably happened well before you speaking or writing about it (how long can you *really* be "surprised"?). You normally only use Past tense there if it was a long time ago and/or you're more interested in referring to your reaction ***then*** than in conveying what you think ***now*** (at time of speaking / writing).

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I feel like the discussion of the "lit crit present tense" can be expanded to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple answer to the question *Which tense, past or present?* because it’s quite dependent on context, and to some extent on personal preference.

A widespread convention for describing art works is that they continue to “do their thing.” Thus it’s completely correct to write

> In *Hamlet*, the title character **has** a famous soliloquy in which he **contemplates** suicide.

The thinking behind this convention, the reason it calls for the present tense, is that the assertion about the play continues as factual even today, centuries after the playwright’s death.

If you mount a new production, the Prince of Denmark **will utter** those same lines that Shakespeare **wrote**. (Note both future and past there.)

One’s reaction to a work can be a one-time event or not. So we can have either

> When I **saw** *Hamlet*, I **cried**

or

> Whenever I **see** *Hamlet* I **cry**.

In a sentence like

> When last night’s Hamlet **said**, “To be, or not to be,” it really moved me

we’re discussing a particular actor’s performance, not the (fictional) behavior of the character. That’s why it’s in the simple past tense: though the play lives on, essentially outside of time, any performance of it is ephemeral and rooted in its moment. Thus because this particular reading of a line by one actual actor took place last night, we use the past tense, *said*.

But as I said, there’s no ironclad rule. As an example, I would not object too much to

> One of my all-time favorite moments from *Hill Street Blues* is the time Detective Washington **found** a severed arm in the street, its watch still intact. He **held** its wrist up to his ear and then **deadpanned**, “Takes a licking and keeps on ticking,” quoting John Cameron Swayze’s sales pitch from those old 1960s ads for Timex watches.

I do think it would sound better in the outside-of-time present tense, but I couldn’t call the use of the past tense wrong.